# Is the sum of a bounded monotone sequence monotone?

Tags: real-analysis

So if I have a sequence ${a_n}$ that is bounded and monotone, is $\sum_{j=1}^{n} {a_n}$ monotone?

Comment: Hint: Let $S_k=\sum_{j=1}^ka_j$, then is easy to see that $S_{k+1}=S_k+a_{k+1}$. What you can say about the last equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{j=1}^na_j$ is monotone if $a_n\ge0$ for all $n$ or $a_n\le0$ for all $n$. If $a_n$ is monotone, $\sum_{j=1}^na_j$ will be eventually monotone, that is, there exists $N$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^na_j$ is monotone for $n\ge N$.

Comment: Note that boundedness is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

$S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i;$
$S_n - S_{n-1} = a_n $ It all depents if $a_n$ is positive or negative. Given that $a_n$ is monotone there are multiple cases. But there is a rank from where $S_n$ is monotone in every case.